# In Python 3, can we store specific function parameters in variable?

Tags: python, function, parameters, dry, functools

I have some functions that have exactly the same parameters. Is there a way to store these parameters to a variable and use it in each one to increase code readability?

Here is the current code:

```
def say_ok(language: Languages = Languages.ENGLISH) -> str: ...

def greet(language: Languages = Languages.ENGLISH) -> str: ...

def goodbye(language: Languages = Languages.ENGLISH) -> str: ...

def laugh(language: Languages = Languages.ENGLISH) -> str: ...
```

Note that Languages is an enumeration.
I would like it to be like this:

```
LANGUAGE_PARAMETER = parameter(language: Languages = Languages.ENGLISH)

def say_ok(LANGUAGE_PARAMETER) -> str: ...

def greet(LANGUAGE_PARAMETER) -> str: ...

def goodbye(LANGUAGE_PARAMETER) -> str: ...

def laugh(LANGUAGE_PARAMETER) -> str: ...
```

Should I use something from typing or functools module?
Thank you very much!

Comment: are all functions using the exact same argument? i.e. all functions should use Languages.ENGLISH at the same time or is there a case where one function might use another Language?

Comment: I did not explain it well, all functions have the same parameters, and the default argument is Languages.ENGLISH. May another Language item will be used

Comment: That sounds like what classes were invented for…

Comment: It kind of feels all you need here is ONE function and a 2d lookup table